# Integration eureka and SBA in the same project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I plan to integrate eureka and Spring Boot Admin in the same project.

When I use `spring boot` version `2.1.14.RELEASE`, `spring boot admin` version `2.1.6` and `spring cloud` version `Greenwich.SR5` it works fine.

[image]

But when I use `spring boot` version `2.3.0.RELEASE`, `spring boot admin` version `2.2.3` and `spring cloud` version `Hoxton.SR4` the browser console got some error.

[image]

[image]

Here is the demo code.
[demo.zip](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/files/4705368/demo.zip)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the below property in your `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-path
```

Try adding this too:

```
eureka.instance.metadata-map.management.context-path: ${server.servlet.context-path}/actuator
```